# What variables can we define in assembly language using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, variables, keyword, masm, dword

This is my code, the program runs fine when I define the third variable as cc, if and when I change it to C, the variable turns blue (indicating that it is a keyword in the assembly language since I have the .dat file installed to highlight assembly language keywords) the debugger gives me an error of ...\Irvine\Examples\ch03\AddSums.asm" exited with code 1.

I have ran the code through breakpoints in the first case too. Everything is good. I am just concerned since this is an assignment for school and the variable needs to be C, why is it not letting me?

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
A DWORD 30
B DWORD 20
cc DWORD 10
D DWORD 5

.code
main PROC
mov eax, A
mov ebx, B
mov ecx, cc
mov edx, D
add eax, ebx
add ecx, edx
sub eax, ecx
mov A, eax

INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: [masm - list of keywords](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/coe/mudawar/coe205/manuals/MASMProgrGuide/D-ReservedWords.pdf) . It's probably a keyword because it can be used with .model, such as `.model flat,c` .